# Multi line textbox breaks characters

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a multiline text box

```asp
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdsISTaddress" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" MaxLength="4000"></asp:TextBox>
```

Based on that textbox I print a html like this

```asp
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lbladd" runat="server" Text="Address:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lbladdval" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Things are fine if I give breaks and enter data in the multi line textbox, but if I don't give breaks, I get horizontal scroll bar in my print page. How to stop this? It should automatically break without creating horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add just CSS `style` attribute as `word-wrap` for `TextBox` like this;

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdsISTaddress" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" MaxLength="4000" style = "word-wrap: break-word;"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped